# View in a list Machine Names

Tags: 7, entities

I am new to Drupal7, and working on a site with different users.

And my probably I am currently encountering is when whenever someone creates a content, field, etc. It generates a machine name.

Using Drupal, it automatically generates one based on the given title of node.
But it won't be saved if the machine name already exist.

Is there anyway to know what machine names exist? And to which this machine name is assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some "object" there is.

- on admin/reports/fields you find a list of every field, with type and machine name
- on admin/structure/types you find a list of every content type, wth machine name

and so on for views, rules and any other "object".

If you need a "report" you could use Views, o make a directly a query.

Comment: You mentioned admin/structure/types or are you referring to admin/structure/content types?

Comment: The correct path is "admin/structure/types" and it's the list of content types

Comment: I see I guess I just misread it, since I still can't make clean URLs to work.